# Google play service and admob doubles the memory of my app

Tags: android, admob, proguard

I am creating my first app. I exported, and the apk size is 1.6 mb. I want admob advertise for monetization. But after integreating google play service and admob when I export it becomes 3.3 mb. This is too annoying as I am trying to minimize the memory.

I have heard about proguard but don't know how to integrate it and if it will really help. I have added this lines in project.properties for proguard

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
```

But when I am trying to export with this line a message pop up saying

```
"Proguart returned with error code 1, see consol"
```

When I see consol, sometimes there is nothing/blank and sometmes error syn: timeout.

I am fighting to pulish my first app since last five days, now I am very frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should use ProGurad, however you can follow these two steps:

**Step 1: Remove unused classes from jar file**

Open the google-play-services.jar in the library project with a zip file manager such as Winrar or 7zip. You will find many folder such as maps, games, just delete the ones you don't need. Make sure you keep common, dynamic, internal, ads .

**Step 2: Remove unused resource from res folder**

Most of the resources in the google-play-services_lib\res folder might be of no use so you can remove it. These include values-af, values-am, .... what you need to keep is color, drawable, drawable-hdpi and values folder.

Refresh and build the google-play-services_lib project and your project. Your apk size should be decreased.